# Where do I find QNX kernel dumps?

Tags: kernel, dump, qnx

Searching for "qnx kernel dump" on google gives a page like this

https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1.update/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_technotes/proc_dump.html

But no information is given as to how I can access this output.

Comment: Did you try /var/dumps
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp? "The directory where dumper saves any dumps that result when a program terminates abnormally" topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.user_guide%2Ftopic%2Ffiles_var.html
You can analyze it with e.g. gdb http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fd%2Fdumper.html

Answer (score 0):

In QNX 7.0, the core dumps are created in `/root`.

Answer (score 0):

In **QNX 7.1**, I can find the core dumps created in `/tmp` (which is mapped to `/dev/shmem`).